# Testimonies of the existence of Mary and Joseph

Tags: history, virgin-mary, joseph-husband-of-mary

There are 30+ historical accounts of Jesus's existence. A subset of these would also seem to be evidence for the existence of Mary and Joseph.

What is the historical evidence (besides what is recorded in Holy Scriptures) of the existence of Mary and Joseph?

Comment: I'm not sure, do you mean non-biblical?

Comment: Why does the proof need to be extra-biblical? Do you subscribe to the theory that a claim is untrustworthy simply because it is in the Bible? You will not find any early sources as trustworthy as those found in the Bible.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast just "evidence". I've removed all mention of "proof."

Comment: @Geremia Thanks, much clearer (am looking forward to answers to this question).

Comment: First of all, there are *no* known eyewitness accounts of the man Jesus. (And there is only one known first-hand account of a post-crucifixion appearance of Jesus.) Second, I too am curious why you are only interested in extra-Biblical sources for Mary and Joseph. However, in answer to your question: As far as I know, there are no extra-Biblical accounts of Mary or Joseph prior to the Infancy Gospel of James, written perhaps in 150 CE. By this time, the traditions of Mary and Joseph had already become saturated with legend, so anything written afterward would be of dubious historical value.

Comment: At least until after 70 CE, no New Testament book (ie  Paul's epistles, *Hebrews* and *Mark*) mentions Joseph. So the first mention of Joseph comes at least a generation after his death.

Comment: I bet you can find a number of things from googling "Mariology" and "Josephology". Mary and Joseph both have their own dedicated fields of study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Joseph and Mary are not mentioned directly, Josephus writes about 93 CE an account of James, brother of Jesus.

> Festus was now dead, and Albinus was but upon the road; so he assembled the sanhedrim of judges, and brought before them the **brother of Jesus, who was called Christ, whose name was James**, and some others, [or, some of his companions]; and when he had formed an accusation against them as breakers of the law, he delivered them to be stoned:
>   https://www.ccel.org/ccel/josephus/complete.ii.xxi.ix.html

In addition, Clement of Alexandria circa 200 CE wrote about Joseph and Mary, though this reference is only found in Eusebius.

> 2. Then James, whom the ancients surnamed the Just on account of the excellence of his virtue, is recorded to have been the first to be made bishop of the church of Jerusalem. This **James was called the brother of the Lord because he was known as a son of Joseph, and Joseph was supposed to be the father of Christ, because the Virgin**, being betrothed to him, “was found with child by the Holy Ghost before they came together,” as the account of the holy Gospels shows.
>      https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf201.iii.vii.ii.html